# Plotting two spirals that counter rotate

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm playing with Vonoroi patterns and using a spiral set of points as the 'seeds' for the cells.

I'm using inkscape to do the Vonoroi and Excel VBA to plot the spiral.

I wrote a simple loop to plot the sprial with an increasing radius and anglular offset to make the spiral.

[image]

This works fine.

What I want to do now is to plot two spirals that are 'joined', I don't know the correct terminolgy, but something like this:

[image]

Can anyone point me at the maths I need to plot something like this? Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: Is this question about using Mathematica software to solve your problem? (It should be possible) Or is it a question in general about the mathematics required in which case you should look at the dedicated forum for Mathematics.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the [hyperbolic tangent spirals](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/spiral/) as a starting point: `ParametricPlot[Table[ReIm[Tanh[(1 + I a) u]], {a, 9}] // Evaluate, {u, -4, 4}, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 45, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 2}}]`

Comment: Will ask on dedicated math page. Sorry...

Comment: @Richard be sure to come back here for help on the Wolfram Language implementation!